# Bash Array Key from User Input

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

So I have a bash script which will scan a directory and run a function on a selected input.

```
    echo -n "
-------------------------------------------------------
            `hostname` Menu
-------------------------------------------------------

Choose your desired Host:
`
i=1
for D in /var/www/*.*/;
    do   
        if [[ -d $D ]]; then
            Hosts[$i]=$D
            echo $i') ' $D
            i=$(($i+1))
        fi
    done
    `
"
read -p "Select: " Input
    Directory="${Hosts[$Input]}";
    ChangePerms;
```

It seems that for some reason, the key is not setting from the array properly.

```
Choose your desired Host:
1)  /var/www/example1.com/
2)  /var/www/example2.com/
+ read -p 'Select: ' Input
Select: 1
+ Directory=
+ ChangePerms
+ true
```

What am I missing? All help is much appreciated!

EDIT:
As a side note, I can run the commands separately and get results.

```
root@web005:/# i=1
root@web005:/# for D in /var/www/*.*/;
>     do
>         if [[ -d $D ]]; then
>             Hosts[$i]=$D
>             echo $i') ' $D
>             i=$(($i+1))
>         fi
>     done
1)  /var/www/example1.com/
2)  /var/www/example2.com/
root@web005:/# read -p "Select: " Input
Select: 1
root@web005:/# Directory="${Hosts[$Input]}";
root@web005:/# echo $Directory
/var/www/example1.com/
root@web005:/#
```

Here is the working code for those who get stuck like me:

```
echo -n "
-------------------------------------------------------
            `hostname` Menu
-------------------------------------------------------

Choose your desired Host:

"
i=1
for D in /var/www/*.*/;
    do   
        if [[ -d $D ]]; then
            Hosts[$i]=$D
            echo $i') ' $D
            i=$(($i+1))
        fi
    done
read -p "Select: " Input
    Directory="${Hosts[$Input]}";
    ChangePerms;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
`
i=1
for D in /var/www/*.*/;
    do   
        if [[ -d $D ]]; then
            Hosts[$i]=$D
            echo $i') ' $D
            i=$(($i+1))
        fi
    done
`
```

which executes in a `subshell`. Therefore, the remainder of your script has no idea what `Hosts` is. (in other words, `Hosts` is empty in the main body of your script). Fill `Hosts` before you present your menu.

Comment: Genius! I would upvote if I had the reputation to do so! Thank you! Edited code with working example.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting seems odd to me.
This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "
-------------------------------------------------------
            `hostname` Menu
-------------------------------------------------------

Choose your desired Host:
"
i=1
for D in /tmp/www/*.*/ ; do   
        if [[ -d $D ]]; then
                Hosts[$i]=$D
                echo $i') ' $D
            i=$(($i+1))
        fi
    done
read -p "Select: " Input
Directory="${Hosts[$Input]}";
echo $Directory
```

Comment: This was the simplest edit to make the answer by @david-c-rankin work! Thank you! I had the funny quotation, because I used to have a static case statement but I wanted this to be portable across all of my servers!